# Nested weight sum

Tags: android, android-layout

**Explaination**

> A warning message used to appear on setting nested weight sums in the
>   layout xml says that it will effect the performance.

**Question 1**

> I don't call I saw it lately. Did they fixed this issue?

**Question 2**

> Setting a weight for a layout doesn't mean that a weight sum to parent is set as well
>   as you know. Does this also considered as setting weight sum to the
>   parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's an Android Lint warning if you're using **nested** linearlayouts that specify layout weights. It's still there. Each nesting level of weighted layouts doubles the number of measure/layout passes required and thus hurts performance. For one level of nesting you don't get the lint warning.
2. Not sure what you mean exactly but does the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) answer your question:

   > Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children.

Comment: I think that means that even if weight sum not specified a +1 measurement will occur. right?

Comment: Yes, if there are any children in the LinearLayout with non-zero `layout_weight`, then there's an implicit non-zero weight sum. Additional measure/layout pass is needed.